# Digitally signing timestamp to a file, event, etc in a way that can be validated by any third party

Tags: timestamp, command-line-interface, digital-signature, gnupg, ca

I believe the simplest way I can summarize this, is that I'd like to **prove that a thing happened at a specific time**, and that that proof can be validated, in a reliable fashion, by any third party. I imagine, because no one trusts me, that some kind of cert authority, or a timestamp-as-a-service would exist, but I really have no idea how to approach this - thus my first question here in so many years (not great at admitting when I need help).

I do realize that this is a problem where "the blockchain" is actually useful, but I am hoping that something a bit (much much) more concrete already exists - ie, I would love to be able to use gpg with some kind of recognized authority, as opposed to some nodejs script that wraps geth and a multigig ethereum node.

Cheers